# call_user_func within class context (with $this defined)

Tags: php

Is there a way how to execute closure in PHP5.3 within a context of an object?

```
class Test {
    public $name='John';

    function greet(){
        eval('echo "Hello, ".$this->name;');

        call_user_func(function(){
            echo "Goodbye, ".$this->name;
        });
    }
}
$c = new Test;
$c->greet();
```

The eval() would work fine, however call_user_func will have no access to $this. (*Using $this when not in object context*).
I am passing "$this" as an argument to closure right now, but that's not exactly what I need.

Comment: Unfortunately call_user_func(array($this,function(){ .. })); wouldn't work, which would be ideal syntax for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access to `$this` is not possible from lambda or closure as of PHP 5.3.6. You'd either have to assign `$this` to a temp var and use that with `use` (which means you will only have the public API available) or pass in/use the desired property. All shown elsewhere on this site, so I won't reiterate.

Access to `$this` is available in Trunk though for PHP.next: http://codepad.viper-7.com/PpBXa2

Comment: How did you manage to answer questions so quickly btw? Is there a live question feed?

Comment: @roman I answered this one pretty late, didn't I? Don't know if there is a live feed. I just press F5 frequently :)

Answer (score 4):

For an actual *closure*, this is about the only way to do it:

```
$obj = $this;
call_user_func(function () use ($obj) {
    echo "Goodbye, " . $obj->name;
});
```

It's probably more elegant to pass the object as parameter as suggested in the other answers (and probably as you're already doing).

Comment: Was about to suggest this. Usually you do `$that = $this;`. At least in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
class Test {
    public $name='John';

    function greet(){
        eval('echo "Hello, ".$this->name;');

        call_user_func(function($obj){
            echo "Goodbye, ".$obj->name;
        }, $this);
    }
}
$c = new Test;
$c->greet();
```

Comment: That's what i'm using now, but it's not exactly setting the context.

Answer (score 0):

```
call_user_func(function($name){
            echo "Goodbye, ".$name;
        }, $this->Name);
```