# PHP call_user_func alternative

Tags: php, oop, fatal-error

I am looking for a pretty equivalent in PHP to its function `call_user_func`.
The problem I am encountering with this function is that it does not go into an "object mode". By this, I mean I cannot use `$this` and other stuff in the class, so pretty much in two words: not oop.

I need this basically as I am dealing with the requested url, parsing it, and seeing if everything is ok and so on, and then doing the following lines:

```
call_user_func(array(ucfirst( $controller . "Controller" ),  '_initAction'), $param);       
call_user_func(array(ucfirst( $controller . "Controller" ), $action . 'Action'), $param);
```

as I want to dynamically call the `"Controller"` and its actions. But I cannot use `$this` in the `$action` methods as it is not OOP.

Here the message I get:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in E:\htdocs\wit\application\controller\InformationController.php on line 6
```

So I hope that somebody could help me.

Could you also tell me if I am approaching this problem in a wrong way?

PS: Please don't recommend me any MVC frameworks that take care of this stuff. I like Zend, but sometimes, its just too heavy :(( I need a lightweight setup for this.

Comment: Your use of `ucfirst` hints at one more issue.

Comment: I asked about something similar recently. Check out my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549724/call-user-func-within-class-context-with-this-defined

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call the object method by passing object in first element of the callback:

```
$class = ucfirst($controller . "Controller");
$controller = new $class();
call_user_func(array($controller,  $action . 'Action'), $param);
```

Actually, you can even use

```
$controller = new $class();
$controller->{$action . 'Action'}();
```

Comment: I go with this answer as it suits me best - actually its simplest answer actually :D thank you and everybody else of course as well

Comment: How to pass an array of parameters through the second usage? I tried an array written in the brackets() but this results in "unsupported operand types"-Error.

Comment: where are params in second example?

Comment: you cannot pass the parameters as array in second example - the `{$action . 'Action'}` is just builds the function name, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how [Glue](https://bitbucket.org/jtopjian/gluephp/src/1d28a390517e/glue.php#cl-61) calls user defined functions. It may point you in the right direction, since users define classes to handle routes.

```
<?php
require_once('glue.php');
$urls = array(
    '/' => 'index'
);
class index {
    function GET() {
        echo "Hello, World!";
    }
}
glue::stick($urls);
?>
```

Comment: This is actually very interesting... it looks like the router in zend framework...I might use it - thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I completely miss the point of your question, I'm sorry. It sounds to me like you're trying to call an object method using `call_user_func`. You can do that, you just pass an array with the object as the first index, and the string name of the method as the second index.

For example, say you have your controller "IndexController" with "index" as your action/method.

```
class IndexController {
    public function index() {
        // $this available here
    }
}

$controller = new IndexController();

// if you know your parameters all ahead of time
call_user_func(array($controller, 'index'), $param1, $param2);

// if you want to pass an unknown number of params
call_user_func_array(array($controller, 'index'), $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$view       =   View::getInstance( $config['view'] );
$err        =   new ErrorController(array(), $view);

//load the class and its method
//pass the params to it 
$class      =   ucfirst( $controller . "Controller" );
if ( class_exists($class) )
{
    $con    =   new $class($param, $view);  
    $act    =   $action . 'Action';
    if ( method_exists($con, $act)  )
    {
        $con->$act();

    }
    else
    {
        $view->setController("error");
        $view->setAction('index');
        $err->indexAction();
    }
}
else
{
    $view->setController("error");
    $view->setAction('index');
    $err->indexAction();
}
```

So this is my solution how i solved my problem. it is based on @AlexAtNet solution and parts of glue that was recommend to me by @Sean

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this way:

```
$controller = new $class();

$method = $action . 'Action';

[$controller, $method]()
```